# Erro: Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou tentando fazer uma tabela html igual a minha tabela do banco de dados, porém, na página que está a tabela aparece o seguinte erro:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted
>   to string in

A parte do código responsável pelo erro é:

```
<?php
//Conexão e consulta ao Mysql
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysqli_select_db($con, 'sis_tam');
$qry = mysqli_query($con, "select * from clientes");

//Pegando os nomes dos campos
$num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($qry);//Obtém o número de campos do resultado

for($i = 0;$i<$num_fields; $i++){//Pega o nome dos campos
    $fields[] = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($qry, $i);
}

//Montando o cabeçalho da tabela
$table = '<table class="table table-hover table-inverse" style="margin-top:50;background-color: #37444a; color:lightgrey;"> <tr>';

for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
    $table .= '<th>'.$fields[$i].'</th>'; //ESSA É A LINHA DO ERRO
}

//Montando o corpo da tabela
$table .= '<tbody style="
    background-color: #86979e;
    color: #37444a;    
">';
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($qry)){
    $table .= '<tr>';
    for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
        $table .= '<td>'.$r[$fields[$i]].'</td>';
    }

    // Adicionando botão de exclusão
    $table .= '<td><form action="banco/deleteC.php" method="post">'; //formulário com método post que vai para deleteF.php
    $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="'.$r['ID'].'">';
    $table .= '<button  class="btn btn-danger">Excluir</button>'; //aqui está o seu botão
    $table .= '</form></td>';
}

//Finalizando a tabela
$table .= '</tbody></table>';

//Imprimindo a tabela
echo $table;

?>
```

A linha que está sendo apontada no erro é:

```
$table .= '<th>'.$fields[$i].'</th>';
```

Eu não uso PDO e não entendo o que possa estar gerando o erro, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que `fetch_field_direct` retorna um objeto e você não pode concatenar esse objeto com uma `string`, por exemplo.

Para exibir o valor você deve utilizar um atributo: Ex's:

```
$fields[$i]->name
$fields[$i]->table
$fields[$i]->max_length
$fields[$i]->flags
$fields[$i]->type
```

Comment: Obrigada, resolveu meu problema